# how to pass a long String args from java app to bash script run spark subbmit?

Tags: java, bash, apache-spark

i i'm using a java app to pass arg to my spark submit bash script. instead of config all in spark-submit, I create a String contains all config of that job and pass it through the args, but it seem that spark can't understand it, what I did wrong?

```
CONF1=$1
CONF='--class "com.at.es_parent_child.SegmentIcebergEsV2" --master yarn --deploy-mode client --queue llap --num-executors 3 --driver-memory 1024m --executor-memory 1024m --executor-cores 4 --name [564889711]es_parent_child.[0].1668574353481 --conf "spark.executor.extraClassPath=/etc/hbase/conf" --conf "spark.driver.extraClassPath=/etc/hbase/conf" --conf "spark.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer" --conf "spark.max.executor.failures=100" --conf "spark.rdd.compress=true" --conf "spark.sql.debug.maxToStringFields=2000" --conf "spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreParquet=false" --conf "spark.default.parallelism=50" --conf "spark.debug.maxToStringFields=2000" --conf "hbase.defaults.for.version.skip=true" --conf "spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=1024" --conf "spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog=org.apache.iceberg.spark.SparkSessionCatalog" --conf "spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog.type=hive" --conf "spark.sql.catalog.iceberg=org.apache.iceberg.spark.SparkCatalog" --conf "spark.sql.catalog.iceberg.type=hive" --conf "spark.sql.adaptive.coalescePartitions.enabled=true" --files "/etc/hbase/conf/hbase-site.xml,/usr/hdp/current/hive-client/conf/hive-site.xml"'
echo "--------------------------------------------"
echo $CONF
echo "--------------------------------------------"

sudo -u cdpcore /bin/sh /build/iceberg/spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-submit $CONF --jars $(echo $JAR_LIB/*.jar | tr ' ' ',') $JAR_MAIN "$2" $3 $4 $5 &

#i use echo of this command and spark still run normal
echo sudo -u cdpcore /bin/sh /build/iceberg/spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-submit $CONF --jars $(echo $JAR_LIB/*.jar | tr ' ' ',') $JAR_MAIN "$2" $3 $4 $5 &
~
```

the script above I pass $1 with a string like CONF, in my java value of CONF is

```
String CONF = "--class "com.at.es_parent_child.SegmentIcebergEsV2" --master yarn --deploy-mode client --queue llap --num-executors 3 --driver-memory 1024m --executor-memory 1024m --executor-cores 4 --name [564889711]es_parent_child.[0].1668574353481 --conf "spark.executor.extraClassPath=/etc/hbase/conf" --conf "spark.driver.extraClassPath=/etc/hbase/conf" --conf "spark.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer" --conf "spark.max.executor.failures=100" --conf "spark.rdd.compress=true" --conf "spark.sql.debug.maxToStringFields=2000" --conf "spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreParquet=false" --conf "spark.default.parallelism=50" --conf "spark.debug.maxToStringFields=2000" --conf "hbase.defaults.for.version.skip=true" --conf "spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=1024" --conf "spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog=org.apache.iceberg.spark.SparkSessionCatalog" --conf "spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog.type=hive" --conf "spark.sql.catalog.iceberg=org.apache.iceberg.spark.SparkCatalog" --conf "spark.sql.catalog.iceberg.type=hive" --conf "spark.sql.adaptive.coalescePartitions.enabled=true" --files "/etc/hbase/conf/hbase-site.xml,/usr/hdp/current/hive-client/conf/hive-site.xml"
"

#and I use 

String[] cmd = {"/bin/sh", System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/spark_job.sh", CONF,
                            zKUrl,""+ task.getPortalId(), task.getJobId(),""+ task.getIndexCode()};
```

the error is

```
22/11/16 12:40:01 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Error: Failed to load class "com.at.es_parent_child.SegmentIcebergEsV2".
```

how can i fix this issue?

Thanks and best regards

Comment: I'm not a Java-guy, but first of all, your assignment to `CONF` looks odd to me.  Print out the value of CONF to see whether it looks OK. In addition, I would put a `set -x` into `spark_job.sh`, for better debugging.

Comment: as i said CONF value is the value of CONF1.

Comment: Ah, I was refering to the Java statement `String CONF =`, not the bash statement `CONF='....'`.

Comment: I'm getting confused. Both the bash script and the java app seem to have long conf strings. Whichever it's meant to be in, get rid of those double quotes - they are redundant where there are no spaces involved. When `$CONF` is finally used, the variable must be double-quoted. I would use a HERE document to construct the string in the first place.

Comment: @g00se hmmm, cause i load another config json file from my java app to build spark job and i don't know how much spark config in that json conf file ( cause it could change and i can't hard code it)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following in your bash script. The value at line 10 might need to be enclosed in singles quotes owing to the square brackets. When `$CONF` is used it must be used as `"$CONF"`

```
CONF=$(cat << EOF
--class com.at.es_parent_child.SegmentIcebergEsV2 \
--master yarn \
--deploy-mode client \
--queue llap \
--num-executors 3 \
--driver-memory 1024m \
--executor-memory 1024m \
--executor-cores 4 \
--name [564889711]es_parent_child.[0].1668574353481 \
--conf spark.executor.extraClassPath=/etc/hbase/conf \
--conf spark.driver.extraClassPath=/etc/hbase/conf \
--conf spark.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer \
--conf spark.max.executor.failures=100 \
--conf spark.rdd.compress=true \
--conf spark.sql.debug.maxToStringFields=2000 \
--conf spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreParquet=false \
--conf spark.default.parallelism=50 \
--conf spark.debug.maxToStringFields=2000 \
--conf hbase.defaults.for.version.skip=true \
--conf spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=1024 \
--conf spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog=org.apache.iceberg.spark.SparkSessionCatalog \
--conf spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog.type=hive \
--conf spark.sql.catalog.iceberg=org.apache.iceberg.spark.SparkCatalog \
--conf spark.sql.catalog.iceberg.type=hive \
--conf spark.sql.adaptive.coalescePartitions.enabled=true \
--files /etc/hbase/conf/hbase-site.xml,/usr/hdp/current/hive-client/conf/hive-site.xml
EOF
)
```

Comment: but sir, how should i pass it from java app, will I keep pass CONF String?

Comment: Why would you need to? You execute the script (which contains that CONF) with Java